# Infinite dimensional vector bundle over manifold of embeddings

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M=Emb(S^1, \mathbb R^2)$. It is an open of $\mathcal C^\infty (S^1,\mathbb R^2)$, so it has a smooth structure, although it is infinite-dimensional. Given an embedding $c\in M$, I am interested in studying $T_cM$. I think it is isomorphic to $\mathcal C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb R^2)$, but I am not entirely sure why.

In general, I think that the tangent bundle should be in some sense "trivial", meaning that $TM\cong M\times \mathcal C^\infty(S^1,\mathbb R^2)$.

Comment: Tangent spaces of open subsets of a vector space are canonically isomorphic to the vector space itself! Same thing as in $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: I see, so fiberwise it's fine. How about globally then?

Comment: This also work globally of course